# Fixed Point Theorem'

Tags: calculus

Let $f (x) = \frac{e^{-x}}{2}-x$. Find, with proof, some interval I for which the fixed point iteration method is guaranteed to converge if the initial guess x0 is in I.

Comment: I don't really how to start the answer to this question. Do you use fixed point theorem and if so how?

Comment: I get it, you must solve $f=0$  Yes, that one is stable.

Answer (score 1):

To provide some hints to get you started. The first thing we have to do is write your function in terms of

$$x = g(x)$$

Then with an initial guess of $x_0$ we want to do

$$x_{i + 1} = g(x_i)$$

Example:

Say we have

$$x^4 - x - 10 = 0$$

Then we can write

$$g(x) = \frac{10}{x^3 - 1}$$

and the fixed point iterative scheme would be

$$x_{i + 1} = \frac{10}{x_i^3 - 1} \ \ i = 0,1,2,\ldots$$

Let your initial guess $x_0$ be $2.0$. Then for various $i$'s  you will see that goes into an infinite loop without converging. Now suppose $g(x) = (x + 10)^{1/4}$ with an initial guess of $x_0$ being $1$ then you will see after $5$ iterations there is convergence.

Comment: I tried using Desmos to see if the fixed point iteration method converges for f(x), but there is a spiral effect for any initial value chosen. How do I find an interval where it is guaranteed to converge?

Comment: Hi Tony, sorry for the late reply. I would suggest just choosing at random in terms of an interval or if you could program it into MATLAB that may be useful to select an interval from there.